# How to run a test in Gitlab for nodejs application

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am new to gitlab so don't have a lot of knowledge about it.

I am trying to setup gitlab to run a test before it builds the image. I have set up a private runner which is configured properly and I can build images but it doesn't work if I run an `npm` command to test the code. Here is my `gitlab-ci.yml` file.

```
image: docker:latest
variables:
  IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
services:
- docker:dind
before_script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p "$CI_BUILD_TOKEN" "$CI_REGISTRY"

stages:
  - build-container-test
  - test-run


build-container-test:
  stage: build-container-test
  script:
    - docker build -t "$IMAGE_TAG" .
    - docker push "$IMAGE_TAG"
  only:
    - test

test-run:
  stage: test-run
  script:
    - npm run test
  only:
    - test
```

This is the error I get while running it.
[image]

Do I need to have `npm` installed separately on gitlab runner to run it or am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An ease example of gitlab-ci file to run the test in the CI:

```
image: node:8.9.4

stages:
  - npm
  - test

npm:
  stage: npm
  script:
    - npm config set registry ${CI_NPM_REGISTRY}
    - npm install
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 days
    when: on_success
    paths:
      - node_modules/

test:
  stage: test
  dependencies:
    - npm
  script:
    - npm test
```

**UPDATE**

I split the pipelines in two, the first one is for install all the dependencies, in this job is used the *artifacts*, the artifacts are for share data between jobs (you can see the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html)). Then in the test job you can run the tests.

Answering the question about environment variables:

- Yes, you can use environment variables, go to the CI/CD configurations and in the Environments variables you can defined you own variables and mark as protected or not (to use this env variables see the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables))

Comment: That worked. Can you please explain what you did there ? How was it able to find npm in the npm stage. And also is there an easy way to supply env variables. My application has a lot of variables and some are secrets. Passing it in the script file would be tedious. Thanks

Comment: But if you do it that way now docker is missing. How can you have docker and npm in the same pipeline?